# Reply to a topic in Discussion board List using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am working with a Discussion board list. I need to create the whole list using CSOM from scratch. To which I was able to make the list and topic inside it as folders. But I am not able to add replies to those topics. If I add replies as ListItem it shows as Topic inside the topic.

I wanted to know how to add replies to topics and also how to add replies to replies.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your goal with `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.CreateNewDiscussionReply` method.

```
public static ListItem CreateNewDiscussionReply(
    ClientRuntimeContext context,
    ListItem parent
)
```

For reply to topic provide topic ListItem as a parameter and for reply to reply provide original reply ListItem as a parameter.

Example

```
 var replyItem = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.CreateNewDiscussionReply(ctx, topicItem);

 replyItem["Title"] = "Test Reply";
 replyItem["Body"] = "Test body Content";
 replyItem.Update();
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy. It really helped me a lot. One more thing, do you how to distinguish between reply to a topic and reply to a reply while reading the replies as items.